# Use NirCmd to pass a key press into XP virtualpc

Tags: shell, scripting, virtualbox, virtual-pc

I am converting a VirtualBox XP image to Virtual PC.  When booting up, the XP image is going through the Found New Hardware Wizard.

At this point in the process, VirtualPC does NOT pass in the mouse or keyboard.  So I am using a script to run nircmd.

The first thing my script does is clears the Reactivation Message by waiting 10 seconds, sending a Tab key press and an Enter key press.

This followed by a 60 second wait for the New Hardware wizard to appear.

Then I move the cursor onto the Next button.

So far the first five entries work correctly.
(I wait one second and send a left mouse click to get the focus.)

Then try to get the hardware wizard to continue.
None of my attempts work.

Left mouse click - nothing happens.

Enter key press - nothing happens.

send key press of Alt+n - nothing happens.

Left mouse double-click - nothing happens.

So I wait 30 seconds and shutdown - That works.

I am open to suggestions.

thank you,
chuck

Script:

nircmdc wait 10000

nircmdc sendkeypress tab

nircmdc sendkeypress enter

nircmdc wait 60000

nircmdc setcursor 390 390

nircmdc wait 1000

nircmdc sendmouse left click

nircmdc wait 1000

nircmdc sendmouse left click

nircmdc wait 1000

nircmdc sendkey enter press

nircmdc wait 1000

nircmdc sendkeypress alt+n

nircmdc wait 1000

nircmdc sendmouse left dblclick

nircmdc wait 30000

nircmdc exitwin shutdown

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here's what happened.

It seems that my script would only run part way when set to run as a StartUp script from the GPO.

When I added the appropriate items to the script and ran that from the user..\startup location, it worked.

I am not sure why, after the user logon was processed, that the move cursor would work, but not the other steps.

Anyways, if someone else runs into this, this is what I used.

Now someone with higher power than I will need to close this one.

thanks,
chuck